# Hololens 2 + Unreal Packaging fails just on device

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have created a minimal Unreal project using the starter content. I have generated signing certificates, and successfully packaged and run the project on the Hololens 2 emulator.

However, when I try to package the same project for my device, I get a the following failure:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):   Using ARM64 architecture for deploying to HoloLens device
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):   ERROR: No required compiler toolchain found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110
PackagingResults: Error: No required compiler toolchain found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): Took 1.0359999s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=6
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.25\UBT-HololensTrial-HoloLens-Development.txt)
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

How can I not have the required compiler toolchain on the device, but it succeeds in the emulator? What steps do I take to get around this?

Comment: When installing VS, you need to add the ARM compilation components.

Comment: Since HoloLens 2 uses an ARM processor, it requires all dependencies to be built for ARM64. We should make sure the MSVC v142-VS 2019 C++ ARM64 build tools (v14.27) component has been installed via Visual Studio Installer.
Besides, we also found a similar topic from the Unreal forum: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/vr-ar-development/1676527-hololens-error-no-required-compiler-toolchain-found-hololens-2-emulator
BTW, if this is your effective solution, recommend posting it as an answer.